# How to set path for go test in vscode

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, visual-studio-code

I have following source tree:

```
/main.go
/templates/t.tmpl
/pkg/templates.go
/pkg/templates_test.go
```

`/pkg/templates.go` defines use of
`var t = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/t.tmpl")`
which is needed for normal project operation, because binary is called from root folder.

And then when I am debugging test from `templates_test.go` from vscode `Must` fails, because go test current directory is `pkg` and not project root

How to make vscode with `go test` to use root project folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the test from the package's source code directory is the default Go behavior.

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags:

> When 'go test' runs a test binary, **it does so from within the
> corresponding package's source code directory**. Depending on the test,
> it may be necessary to do the same when invoking a generated test
> binary directly.

To change the behavior, either use the relative path (e.g. [go project's template package test](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4fea5935f5f03b5037c792f8d5f5aa4cba90f1d6/src/text/template/multi_test.go#L133)), or change the desirable directory you want at the beginning of test program (e.g. `os.Chdir` from TestMain, etc).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to define a test environment variable in `.vscode/settings.json` or in `settings.json` of your vscode:

```json
{
  "go.testEnvVars": {
    "WORKSPACE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
}
```

Once you have defined this variable, you can use it to change the current working directory as follows:

```golang
os.Chdir(os.Getenv("WORKSPACE_DIR"))
```

Comment: The first JSON? is invalid, as there is an opening curly bracket, but no matching closing one.

Comment: @TheDiveO My bad, just a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To recap things up

### 1. Env var

Solution with defining a test environment variable in .vscode/settings.json or in settings.json of your vscode:

{
"go.testEnvVars": {
"WORKSPACE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
}

Works well only in vscode, running go test from bash outside may need speccial care, which, for "outside" world will always led to a question and ping pong. example "hey you have a failing test - oh you will need to set up additional variable in your side". may work but feels crutchy

### 2 embed.FS

Finally solved that with embed fs. it has a con that it cannot be changed at runtime, but in our case all our files under /templates can be threated as static ones - much more interesting solution, drawback is that you acnt modify templates on the fly, but in our secnario we havent any need for that